Trying to achieve "some sort of hemicompactness" in a Tychonoff space
Let $X$ be a Tychonoff space, i.e. Hausdorff and completely regular. Additionally, consider a map $\psi: X \to (0,\infty)$ such that $K_R := \psi^{-1}((0,R])$ is compact in $X$, for every $R>0$. Note that $\psi$ is not assumed to be continuous.
It is clear that $X = \bigcup_{n \geq 1} K_n$, and hence $X$ is $\sigma$-compact. I would like to find a way to guarantee that, given an arbitrary compact $K \subset X$, there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $K \subset K_N$. Potentially by adding assumptions on $X$, though I'd like to keep $X$ as general as possible.
I've tried assuming that $X$ is locally compact, which would make $X$ exhaustible by compacts. Given an exhaustion $(C_n)_{n\geq 1}$ of $X$, it is clear to me that $K$ would be contained in some $C_N$. However, it's not clear that the exhaustion is given by sets of the form $K_n = \psi^{-1}((0,n])$, and so it doesn't answer the problem.
Do you have any ideas? Thanks in advance for having a look.

If I understand the question I don't think this is really possible. Take a countable compact set and map each point to a different integer. Then the entire space is not contained in any preimage.

I take it that rather than assume discontinuity of $\psi$ we should not assume that it is continuous.
The assumption that such a $\psi$ exists does indeed imply $\sigma$-compactness, but the converse also holds: assume $X=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty K_n$ with each $K_n$ compact and, wlog, $K_n\subseteq K_{n+1}$ always. Define $\psi(x)=\min{n:x\in K_n}$; then $\psi$ satisfies your assumption.
So the answers that you seek are the answers that one gets for $\sigma$-compact spaces.

@KPHart Indeed, you are right the map $\psi$ is not necessarily discontinuous, I just wanted to emphasise that it's not assumed continuous. I've edited the post. Your second point is also curious, I hadn't noticed that the converse holds. Thank you. Do you have any suggestions on how to achieve the inclusion $K \subset K_N$? I'm okay with assuming extra structure on $X$, like being locally compact or metrisable. But I wanted to avoid tweaking the map $\psi$...

@Gaspar You cannot expect an answer depending on the space only: in a countable compact space use an enumeration of the space to find an increasing cover by finite sets. The space is very nice, but this particular cover does nothing useful.
Or in the unit interval take $K_n={0}\cup[2^{-n},1]$; you will not capture any compact set that has $0$ as an accumulation point. So, even for compact metrisable spaces there is no guarantee without any assumptions on $\psi$ (which means that some tweaking may be necessary).

@KPHart I see your point... Thank you for the insights and the crystal clear examples!
